# CHROME WebRequest APIs example error: "onBeforeRequest" can only be used in extension processes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I try to test a example of [`WebRequest` APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.webRequest.html#examples), but throw error:

> "onBeforeRequest" can only be used in extension processes.
>   manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "example",
   "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "experimental",
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
    "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "foo.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ]
}
```

`foo.js` is exactly the example 1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chrome extension functions (which includes the webRequest API) cannot be used in content scripts (`foo.js` in your example). If you wish to use webRequest from a content script, you can use the [messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) functionality to talk to the extension's [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html). The background page can use webRequest directly and relay the response (if any) back to the content script.

Comment: Thank you. I am a little too fast to try those API... not even read through the document... now it works as expect.

Comment: @Huang, Chrome's documentation team need to learn from the PHP documentations which are written in real proper tutorial style.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a background page in the manifest file and the appropriate permissions in the manifest so the background page can access the webRequest APIs.  See this example: [chrome.webRequest not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502691/chrome-webrequest-not-working)

As Mihai mentioned, if you need to have the content script perform the action, check this page out: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Add this to your content script (you can change greeting to action and hello to which action the background script should perform):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

Add this to your background page (you can do if statements and peform different actions based on the message):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```