# Create an alert every page load with Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first time messing around with extensions and what I am trying to do is very simple yet I can't seem to get it to work.

I simply want an alert to be called every time a page on google is loaded.

In my manifest.json I have:

```
{
"name": "Bypass shib",
"version": "1.0",
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
  "js": ["secondScript.js"]
}
],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Okay now in my secondScript.js I have:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "alert('test')"});
```

Shouldn't this execute the alert whenever a page is loaded? If not can somebody explain why it's not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console reveals the following message:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: "executeScript" can only be used in extension processes.
> See the content scripts documentation for more details.
> ```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223233/chrome-webrequest-apis-example-error-onbeforerequest-can-only-be-used-in-exte) suggests "Chrome extension functions cannot be used in content scripts," which could be what you're running into.

For completeness, the `secondScript.js` that worked for me was as follows:

```
console.log("test");
//chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "alert('test')"});
alert("test");
```

Comment: Oh, and to share a face-palm piece of advice, make sure your manifest uses https if the url you're looking at uses https.

Comment: this does not work. The script gets executed only if you click on the extension and not on page load

Answer (score 1):

[Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) do **not** have access to **any** of the `chrome.tabs.*` API methods.

To display an alert on every page, remove the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method, and let your `secondScript.js` just contain:

```
alert('Test');
```

In a Chrome extension, there are **three** different kinds of scopes in which JavaScript can run. The understanding of this separation is essential for writing Chrome extensions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916089/938089?chrome-extension-auto-run-a-function).