# chrome.webRequest not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement the chrome.webRequest API in my extension but for some reason it's just not working no matter what I do. Can someone post an example of usage? or correct my mistakes? Basically what I'm trying to do is to intercept the recieved headers from a response.

This is an implementation for onBeforeSendHeaders but I'd like to use OnHeadersRecieved as well
:

```
var requestFilter = {
    urls: [ "<all_urls>" ]
  },
  // The 'extraInfoSpec' parameter modifies how Chrome calls your
  // listener function. 'requestHeaders' ensures that the 'details'
  // object has a key called 'requestHeaders' containing the headers,
  // and 'blocking' ensures that the object your function returns is
  // used to overwrite the headers
  extraInfoSpec = ['requestHeaders','blocking'],
  // Chrome will call your listener function in response to every
  // HTTP request
  handler = function( details ) {
    alert(details);
    var headers = details.requestHeaders,
      blockingResponse = {};

    // Each header parameter is stored in an array. Since Chrome
    // makes no guarantee about the contents/order of this array,
    // you'll have to iterate through it to find for the
    // 'User-Agent' element
    for( var i = 0, l = headers.length; i < l; ++i ) {
      if( headers[i].name == 'User-Agent' ) {
        headers[i].value = '>>> Your new user agent string here <<<';
        break;
      }
      // If you want to modify other headers, this is the place to
      // do it. Either remove the 'break;' statement and add in more
      // conditionals or use a 'switch' statement on 'headers[i].name'
    }

    blockingResponse.requestHeaders = headers;
    return blockingResponse;
  };

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener( handler, requestFilter, extraInfoSpec );
```

this is my manifest file:

```
    {
   "background_page": "iRBackground.html",
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "Off.png",
      "popup": "iRMenu.html"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "Content.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
   "description": "***",
   "icons": {
      "128": "On128x128.png",
      "16": "On.png",
      "48": "On48x48.png"
   },
   "key": "****",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "***",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "notifications", "unlimitedStorage", "webRequest", “webRequestBlocking”, “<all_urls>”],
   "update_url": "***/Chrome/UpdateVersion.xml",
   "version": "1.3"
}
```

the error I get from Chrome is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeSendHeaders' of undefined`

Anyone see anything wrong??? thanks

Comment: The `webRequest` API is only available to the extension's process (such as the background/event page).

Comment: This snippet is written in my background page..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well for an example of usage I can give you this working code. I wrote it this way because the other way seems backwards to me but that is just my personal preference, they should both work the same.

**Manifest**

```
{
  "name": "Chrome webrequest test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A test for webrequest",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bgp.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

**bgp.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
  var headers = details.requestHeaders,
  blockingResponse = {};

  // Each header parameter is stored in an array. Since Chrome
  // makes no guarantee about the contents/order of this array,
  // you'll have to iterate through it to find for the
  // 'User-Agent' element
  for( var i = 0, l = headers.length; i < l; ++i ) {
    if( headers[i].name == 'User-Agent' ) {
      headers[i].value = '>>> Your new user agent string here <<<';
      console.log(headers[i].value);
      break;
    }
    // If you want to modify other headers, this is the place to
    // do it. Either remove the 'break;' statement and add in more
    // conditionals or use a 'switch' statement on 'headers[i].name'
  }

  blockingResponse.requestHeaders = headers;
  return blockingResponse;
},
{urls: [ "<all_urls>" ]},['requestHeaders','blocking']);
```

Comment: Hi, I created a folder with 2 files: manifest.json and bgp.js and entered the data u gave respectively and loaded the both as an unpacked extension. later I tried the code which was not working but later I tried to insert some alert()'s into bgp.js which doesn't trigger anything as well.... have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1326293 This is exactly what I have and it is working just fine. Here, I put the files in a [zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12636410/webRequest.zip). Extract it and then try again. Are there any messages in the extension console at all?

Comment: thanks, I found out the problem was my chrome version... nevertheless your example helped :) thanks

Comment: @user1326293 That was actually going to be my next question. I am glad you got it to work.

Comment: Will this also work for adding Content-Length to the headers?

Comment: nm, I figured out how to edit Content-Length. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789841/can-i-inject-a-content-length-header-into-chrome

Comment: Replace `"<all_urls>"` to your needs like `*://*/*`

Answer (score 12):

I just fixed this in my extension here: https://github.com/devinrhode2/tweet-bar
What I needed to do was use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener`, but that also meant adding in the `webRequest, webRequestBlocking` permissions.. would be better to use declarativeWebRequest, but this project isn't that important to me.

Key things:

- `manifest.json "background": { "persistent": true,`
- `"permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking",`

When you make these changes in the manifest.json, you should actually consider re-installing the extension just to make sure the change is being picked up.

This is my filter code. Yours should not be identical. See the docs here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener((req) => {
  console.log('onBeforeSendHeaders');
  req.requestHeaders.forEach(function(header, index){
    console.log(header.name+':', header.value);
    if (headers[header.name.toLowerCase()]) {
      console.log('set header:'+header.name, 'to:'+headers[header.name.toLowerCase()]);
      req.requestHeaders[index].value = headers[header.name.toLowerCase()]
    }
  })
  return {requestHeaders: req.requestHeaders};
},{
  urls: ['https://twitter.com/i/tweet/create'],
  types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
},[
  'blocking',
  'requestHeaders'
]);
```

I also added these headers to my xhr request, which doesn't hurt, makes you appear more similar to the normal site:

```
  //add headers:
  var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    accept: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    origin: 'https://twitter.com',
    referer: 'https://twitter.com/',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  };
  console.log('change')
  Object.keys(headers).forEach((header) => {
    postXhr.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
  })
```

Comment: "...you should actually consider re-installing the extension just to make sure the change is being picked up." Reinstalling the extension did the trick for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the required permissions for the extension in manifest.json, you might not need webRequestBlocking depending on what u want to do.

```
...
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking" 
  ],"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
}
...
```

After adding the required permissions for your extension in the manifest.json file, make sure you click on the **update button** and if that does not work or the browser does not have an update button then **reinstall the extension**.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't Update the extension after adding the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the manifest config

```
"permissions": [ 
    "webRequestBlocking"
    ,"webRequest"
    ,"http://*.beibei.com/*"
],
"background" : {
    "page"       : "xxx.html",
    "persistent" : true
}
```

Here is the javascript demo code

```
$( function() {
    // add event listners
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) { 
            console.log('onBeforeRequest', details);
        },
        {urls: ["http://www.beibei.com/"]},
        []
    );

    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
        function(details) {
            console.log('onBeforeSendHeaders', details);
        },
        {urls: ["http://www.beibei.com/"]},
        ["requestHeaders"]
    );

    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( 
        function(details) {
            console.log('onCompleted', details);
        },
        {urls: ["http://www.beibei.com/"]},
        []
    );

    // do a GET request, so that relative events will be fired, need jquery here
    $.get('http://www.beibei.com/');
});
```