# Can I inject a Content-Length header into Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my first Chrome Extension and it has been quite a learning experience. I'm almost done, but this last piece is killing me.

I know Google doesn't want you to use Content-Length (as stated [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)), but I'm working with an API who's authentication requires it when I POST. [This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) says it can do it but I feel like what I wrote should work. Was this recently blocked in a new version of Chrome?

These are the headers I am sending:

```
{
    "ReplaceHeaders": true,
    "rh-Authentication": "<my auth token>",
    "rh-Timestamp": "<timestamp>",
    "rh-Content-Length": body.length
}
```

This is the section that replaces the "rh" headers with the new headers (everything with "rh-", except for the "rh-" if that even makes sense.):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(data) {
    newHeaders = false;

    _.find(data.requestHeaders, function(header) {
        if ((header.name === "ReplaceHeaders") && (header.value)) {
            _.find(data.requestHeaders, function(h) {
                if (h.name.substring(0, 3) === "rh-") {
                    if (newHeaders === false) { newHeaders = []; }
                    newHeaders.push({
                        name: h.name.substring(3, h.name.length),
                        value: h.value
                    });
                }
            });
            return;
        }
    });

    if (!!newHeaders) {
        // Update headers
        return {requestHeaders: newHeaders};
    }
}, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

When I make a GET request I don't have the "rh-ContentLength" header and it works fine (I can see onSendHeaders, onHeadersReceived, etc.). Everything is replaced and the response is as expected. But when I make a POST request with "rh-Content-Length" I only see onSendHeaders and nothing after that.

My onSendHeaders for both GET and POST have the newly formatted headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I posted that at 3:00 AM. After getting some much needed sleep, I woke up this morning and talked to a friend about it. He pointed out that the mistake was actually in my ajax call. I fixed that and now I can send Content-Length from my extension. The above code does work.

A few notes for the code I posted above for anybody searching for this later:

- I'm using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to loop through the arrays
- This strips all other headers and only adds the headers starting with "rh-". You may or may not want that.
- You have to have ["requestHeaders", "blocking"] as your last argument in onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener()
- In your manifest.json permissions make sure you have "webRequest" and "webRequestBlocking"

Although not tested, this should work on other headers that Chrome says it won't pass. Here is a list of the headers Google says it doesn't provide in onBeforeSendHeaders (as documented [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote)):

- Authorization
- Cache-Control
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Host
- If-Modified-Since
- If-None-Match
- If-Range
- Partial-Data
- Pragma
- Proxy-Authorization
- Proxy-Connection
- Transfer-Encoding

Hope this helps.

Comment: Amazing, this actually works. Even while Google does not provide read access to these headers as stated in the documentation, **write access is still allowed**. In other words 
    `e.requestHeaders.push({'name': 'Content-Length','value': '123'});` works, along with others like `e.requestHeaders.push({'name': 'Host', 'value': 'asdfghhjjk'});`