# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm trying to build my own chrome extension and I'm trying to add an event handler using `onBeforeRequest`.

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "My extension",
    "description": "some descrpition",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webNavigation",
        "management",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
            "js/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
     },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "imgs/img.png",
        "default_title": "extension"
    },
    "icons" : {
      "64" : "imgs/vergrootglas.png"  
    }
}
```

My `background.js`:

```
function callback(param1,param2,param3){
    alert(param1);
    alert(param2);
    alert(param3);
}
//alert("test");



chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callback);
```

I got this loaded into my chrome. But everytime I get this message in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of
>   undefined

I can't figure out what I'm oding wrong, I've found this:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

But  the example of the code seems to be quite the same as what I do.
What am I missing here?

Comment: you can't do that in a content script AFAIK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHROME WebRequest APIs example error: "onBeforeRequest" can only be used in extension processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223233/chrome-webrequest-apis-example-error-onbeforerequest-can-only-be-used-in-exte)

Comment: So, how should I do that then?

Comment: communicate between the extension script and the content script using whatever means chrome extension API gives you (I only know firefox addons sorry, they use `?.port.emit` and `?.port.on` where ? is `self` or something else - not sure chrom works the same way

Comment: So, I've changed my `manifest.json` so the script will run in the background. That's what I understood from the url you provided.

Comment: that works too ... I assumed you needed to do something in a content script

Comment: Well, I can get an alert now as soon as the extension is loaded. But when I use an event handler nothing happens and I get no errors or warnings.

Comment: @FIA2008, this doesn't make any sense. Can you upload the extension and link it in a comment here? Also use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: Please update the rest of the question, not just the code. The error you describe no longer applies. I can answer your question if you make the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above don't make sense to me.  There is a background script above and it seems to have appropriate permissions...  Some extra comments that might help...

You need to add a background page in the manifest file and the appropriate permissions in the manifest so the background page can access the webRequest APIs.  See this example: [chrome.webRequest not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502691/chrome-webrequest-not-working)

As Mihai mentioned, if you need to have the content script perform the action, check this page out: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Add this to your content script (you can change greeting to action and hello to which action the background script should perform):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

Add this to your background page (you can do if statements and peform different actions based on the message):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue, except the problem for me was unrelated to permissions and it was in fact a Webpack issue.

My background script was accidentally being bundled with my content script. Background js was exporting certain constants that content script was using, causing methods restricted to background file (such as `chrome.webRequest`) to be called as part of content script, hence the cannot read property of undefined…